# how to convert json object to geojson on leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson

```js
var markers = JSON.parse('[{"latitude":22.3677333333333,"longitude":59.83935},
{"latitude":22.3366,"longitude":59.8369333333333},
{"latitude":22.3362666666667,"longitude":59.8368},
{"latitude":22.3359,"longitude":59.8368833333333},
{"latitude":22.3356,"longitude":59.83685},
{"latitude":22.3352833333333,"longitude":59.8367333333333},
{"latitude":22.3348833333333,"longitude":59.83675},
{"latitude":22.3345,"longitude":59.83675},
{"latitude":22.3320833333333,"longitude":59.8377333333333}]');
```

*i need to convert my data to point in layer map*

Comment: Pure code-writing requests are off-topic on Stack Overflow -- we expect 
questions here to relate to *specific* programming problems -- but we 
will happily help you write it yourself! Tell us 
[what you've tried](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and where you are stuck. 
This will also help us answer your question better.

Comment: Please read this- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask